# Keeping values of a variable only if the unique values belong to a list

Tags: stata

I am working in Stata. I have a micro dataset, so for each state I have data of different individuals for different years. I want to keep the data for only a few states.
The problem is that there are not the same number of individuals in each state so the command
`keep if _n <= _N/2`  will not work.

So first, I created a new dataset with the unique values of the state column and followed the keep if process. And I stored the state numbers in a list.
Now I imported my original dataset and want to keep if the values of state are in the list.

I tried the command `` keep if inlist(levelsof STATEFIP, `req_list') `` but it did not work.

Can someone help me figure this problem out? How do I keep the values in the data only for the states which are available in the list?

I created a new dataset first, with one column my_list. Then I did the following:

```
sort my_list
egen random = mean(runiform()), by(my_list)
sort random my_list
keep if _n <= _N/2

levelsof mylist, local(list)
local req_list ""
foreach value of local list{
    localreq_list `"`req_list' `value'"'
}

drop random my_list

use "path\to\mydta.dta"

keep if inlist(STATEFIP, `req_list') *this kept deleting the entire dataset
keep if inlist(levelsof STATEFIP, `req_list') *levelsof not found
```

Comment: Hi Biswajit! Welcome to StackOverflow! I am not sure I follow what you are trying to do. Can you provide a mock data set with 3 States with 5-10 individuals in each where you show what you have and what you want? See the Stata command `dataex` to help create data sets that are easy to share here.

Comment: The first argument of `inlist()` can't include another command. It could be a variable name or a constant.